# auto re-size div on mouse over

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I am trying to auto re-size a series of div on mouse over. The effect is working but it's bit slow. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
$('#Main').delegate('div', 'mouseover', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").animate({"height":"290px"}, 500).addClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass('highlight').animate({"height":"200px"},500);
});
```

Check on Fiddle for working demo--

http://jsfiddle.net/dsnegi/y8LrT/

Answer (score 1):

The '500' in your function call is your time interval. 500 is milliseconds. Reduce this to make it faster. However, keep in mind that JS animations are at their very core a "hack" (I use them, too, but let's call a spade a spade!). You're just resizing and repositioning elements over a time interval on a pixel grid using a rendering engine truly meant for static layouts. Smoothness of the animation will be partly predicated on how fast your computer is and which browser you're using.

For this kind of hover effect, I would strongly consider researching CSS3 animations instead, which are going to be smoother and can be hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code with `.on()` instead of `.delegate()` and I *think* it's a little faster.  I also added some `.stop()` functions to get rid of extra unneeded animations to make it a little slicker and faster (less animation going on should be faster).  You can also tweak the duration of the animations, but I tried to make it work a little faster by performance and not just changing a parameter that I am assuming you chose.

http://jsfiddle.net/y8LrT/3/

Comment: `.delegate()` is just aliased to `.on()` now. There won't be a performance difference. The link you posted doesn't seem to have the stop functions unless I'm imagining things! Did you forget to 'save' it first?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to save that.  Address of fiddle is now updated, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

really appreciate it.

tried yours suggestion but what best works for me was to use "mouseenter" instead of mouseover.

i have updated the script http://jsfiddle.net/dsnegi/y8LrT/4/

cheers